# Windows metro apps - write and read text files in C#?

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-8

creating text file:

```
var myFile = "test";
var folderUsed = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var fileOption = Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting;
var createdFile = await folderUsed.CreateFileAsync(myFile, fileOption);
```

writing a string into created text file:

```
var writeThis = "write this ";
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(createdFile, writeThis);
```

However, it doesn't specify in which part the text file will be created, I'd like to create it inside the package of my app, not in somewhere else in my computer, is it possible?

And secondly, when I execute the second code again, I'd like my file to be written as "write this write this ", not replace the old file and create another one.

Comment: what do you mean with "create it inside the package of my app"? Do you mean the folder in which the app has been installed?

Comment: have you tried to put them in the assets folder?

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

since the other folders such as installation folders are restricted and not allowed for read-write operations. Windows Store apps are pretty restricted in this area.

This link is also useful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758325.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If your files are in the assets folder then you can access them by:

```
String path = "ms-appx:///Assets/" + Domain + ".txt";
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(path));
string Value = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
```

Comment: How do you get `Domain`?

Answer (score 0):

"However, it doesn't specify in which part the text file will be created, I'd like to create it inside the package of my app, not in somewhere else in my computer, is it possible?"

It's actually 'almost' the only thing possible! your application has explicit access to it's own 'LocalFolder' folder, 'RoamingFolder' location which can be shared between application instances or 'TemporaryFolder' for stuff which gets ditched.

You can save files to thing like pictures library using Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.pictureLibrary if you want, and you can get read only access to your installation folder using 'Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.installedLocation' if you so wish.